# Pivot Table to count number of products at multiple locations

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

This is my data sheet below

[image]

and I am trying to create a pivot table to count the number of products at each location

desired end state

[image]

I used the location 1 as the row and add the counts of the other locations but i am not getting accurate end result in the pivot table. Do i need to transpose my data?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your data is not in a format that can be summarized with a pivot table.

Comment: Looks like all you want is a `COUNTIF` for each location

Comment: Hmm if all your data was somehow in a single column it would work but I don't think the pivot can count across different fields. You could perhaps count per location field then add those afterwards... but I would just `=COUNTIF($B$2:$E$7, "New York")`. In Office 365 you can use `UNIQUE($B$2:$E$7)` to generate a unique lists of locations - then use that as input to the countif formula.

Comment: Filter location first and then try the COUNTIF function.

Answer (score 1):

Select your data and use Data>From Table/Range
[image]

You'll see this in the Power Query Editor:
[image]

Select the Product column, then use Transform>Unpivot Columns>Unpivot other columns

[image]

You'll see this:

[image]

Use Data>Close & Load To. In the dialog, select 'PivotTable report' and make sure you select 'Add this data to the data model':

[image]

Adding this to the data model means you can now use the 'Distinct Count' aggregation method, and you can create your pivot table as desired:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Office 365, generate a unique list of locations using `=UNIQUE($B$2:$E$7)` in say G2:G10, then in H2 (and copy down):

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$E$7, G2)
```

If you don't have Office 365, and really want to use a pivot table, unwrap your table into a single column, put "Locs" in say G1, and in G2 put (and copy downwards)

```
=INDEX($B$2:$D$5,INT((ROW()-2)/4)+1,MOD(ROW()-2,4)+1)     ....replace "4" with the number of location columns, replace "2" with the starting row number (G2 in my example)
```

Now pivot G1:G25 and put Locs in rows and count of Locs in values.