# Converting columns into rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion

So I have a table that on excel looks like the following:

| year | Jan | Feb | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 44 | 1 |
| 2001 | 33 | 55 | 2 |
| 2002 | 44 | 3 | 1 |
| 2003 | 55 | 22 | 1 |
| 2004 | 22 | 34 | 3 |
| 2005 | 33 | 23 | 3 |
| 2006 | 43 | 45 | 3 |

So the last 3 columns represents the one and the first column represents the year. I want to create a time series chart, I need to convert this table into a table that only has 2 columns.The first column would represent the date (Jan 2000, Feb 2001) and the second column would represent the values. Could you please tell me how to do it? I tried the "transpose" function but it doesn't creat what I need.

Comment: Actually, a three column format would probably work best so you don't have to join together the year and month - Excel will quite happily plot a chart where the X axis is a category and subcategories from two columns eg year, month.
How many years' data do you have? If less than a couple of dozen and doing this as a one-off  I would just go for a copy/paste 12 times, one below another, with an inserted column for the months for each batch. If you need to be able to repeat this with new data or for multiple data sets, we need to be a bit cleverer.

Comment: Use the "unpivot other columns" method described here: https://superuser.com/questions/1637974/pivot-table-to-count-number-of-products-at-multiple-locations/1637996#1637996

Comment: Try to use Unpivot Columns in Excel Power Query editor..

Answer (score 1):

Using Power Query, you can select the `Year` column and **Unpivot** the other columns.

- Select a cell in your data table
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range
- In the PQ UI, select `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Take note of the table name in Line 2
- Paste the M-Code below to replace the code in that window.
- Examine the comments, and also the Applied Steps window selections, to understand what is going on
- The year/month will be converted to **real** dates equal to the first of each month

  - Format them how you want in Excel for display.
- Close and Load (or Load To)
- *Note that all steps can be done directly from the UI*

### M-Code

```
let

//change table name to your actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],

//Unpivot the columns other than the year
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"year"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//merge the year and month ("Attribute") columns
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {
        {"year", type text}}, "en-US"),{"year", "Attribute"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"month/year"),

//change to a real date by changing the Type => date
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns",{{"month/year", type date}, {"Value", Int64.Type}})
    
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

Comment: It's nice idea but the OP wants JAN & FEB data for 2000 and 2001 only !!

Answer (score 0):

The following is an approach based on Dynamic Arrays (DA) and using the LET function, so it will require Excel 2016 or Microsoft 365.  As it is DA based, it will work on Excel for Mac and does not require data refreshing or other pivot table engagement - it is pure Excel Formula based.

Let's say that the data are in cells A1 to D8 as shown above. In Power Query parlance, we would say that you want to "**Unpivot** B1:D8 **By** A1:A8".  But you are wanting to compute dates from the By column and the relative column position of the Unpiv Matrix.

The following is a modification of a general unpiv array formula that follows the logic of Power Query Unpivot, but delivers the computed dates as a combined column instead of By column and Attribute.

```
=LET( unPivMatrix, B1:D8,
      byYears, A1:A8,
       upC, COLUMNS( unPivMatrix ),
       byC, COLUMNS( byYears ),
       dmxR, MIN( ROWS( unPivMatrix ), ROWS( byYears ) ) - 1,
       upCells, dmxR * upC,
       upSeq, SEQUENCE( upCells,, 0 ),
       upHdr, INDEX( INDEX( unPivMatrix, 1, ),  1,  SEQUENCE( upC ) ),
       upBody, INDEX( unPivMatrix,  SEQUENCE( dmxR ) + 1,  SEQUENCE( 1, upC ) ),
       byBody, INDEX( byYears,  SEQUENCE( dmxR ) + 1,  SEQUENCE( 1, byC ) ),
       mux, INDEX( upBody, upSeq/upC + 1, MOD( upSeq, upC ) + 1 ),
       demux, IFERROR( INDEX(
                             INDEX( byBody,
                                    IFERROR( INT( SEQUENCE( upCells, byC,0 )/byC/upC ) + 1, MOD( upSeq, upC ) + 1 ),
                                             SEQUENCE( 1, byC + 1 ) ),
                             upSeq + 1, SEQUENCE( 1, byC + 2 ) ),
                       mux ),
       IFERROR( INDEX( DATE( INDEX( demux,,1), MOD( upSeq, upC ) + 1, 1 ),
                       SEQUENCE( upCells ),
                       {1,2}),
                mux )
 )
```

The output would result in this:
[image]

**How this works - Reading the inputs**

The inputs are the range that you want to unpivot that I called **unPivMatrix** B1:D8 (which can be of any dimensions you need) and the columns that you want to unpivot them by that I called **byYears** A1:A8.

The formula first calculates the number of columns in each matrix: **upC** unpivot columns and **byC** by columns. From these it calculates **dmxR** (demultiplexed rows): how many rows of values will be delivered in the unpivot by taking the minimum of the rows of unPivMatrix and byMatrix and subtracting 1 because unPivMatrix has a header. Taking the MIN is an error prevention step in the event that the inputs have a different number of rows, which is an error by definition.

These values are used to create shaping variables that will be used later to form the output. **upCells** is the number of values that will be unpivoted and is used to generate an index pattern called **upSeq** that counts off the number of values from 0 which will used inside of the INDEX functions later. We start with 0 because upSeq will be modulated to form correct indexation of the inputs and outputs.

Now we will break down the parts of the matrices so that we can multiplex them.  The parts look like this:

[image]

There is an unpivot header (**upHdr**) that contains the identifier of the value data (in this case, Jan, Feb, March). These will be multiplexed into a column that will later be placed next to each value that is unpivoted. upHdr is created by putting the whole unPivMatrix into an INDEX function and reading Row 1 and all of the columns. I nested that INDEX function into another INDEX that reshapes the horizontal array to a vertical array using a vertical SEQUENCE of size upC.

**upBody** contains the values that we want to unpivot via multiplexing. It is created by putting the upMatrix into an INDEX and shaping it by the number of rows that will be output `SEQUENCE( dmxR ) + 1` **§** against each of the columns to be read SEQUENCE( upC ).
**byBody** contains the data that will be multiplexed against each value in the upBody.  It is created the same way as upBody.

*§ - add 1 to skip the header row*

**How this works - Shaping and writing the outputs**

The output will be shaped like this:

[image]

We now create a column called **mux** of the values (using Power Query terminology) that will be multiplexed against each month column and byBody row. It is created by putting upBody into INDEX and then reshaping it into a multiplex pattern created by rows of

`upSeq/upC + 1` which yields a row of `{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,...}`

and columns of

`MOD( upSeq, upC )` + 1 which yields a column of `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;1;...}`.

The output for mux will be the content of the unPivMatrix.

**How this works - Demultiplexing the parts into the output**

Now that the easy part is done, it is time to go after the hard stuff - bringing this all together into a single dynamic array.  Putting multiple arrays together requires a trick and this trick has to be applied twice because, as you can see, we are bringing three tables together. The trick is like having an APPEND function like:

`APPEND( APPEND( table1, table2 ), table3 )`.

To combine two arrays, you put the first array into an INDEX and then reference cells that are outside of the array to force a #REF! error.  For example, if I have a 3 x 2 array of letters A through F and I reference cell 3, 3, it will throw a reference error.

[image]

Now you can exploit the errors by replacing them with the table that you want to append by wrapping the INDEX in an IFERROR.  It is kind of like:

```
IFERROR( INDEX( table1,
                SEQUENCE( table1.rows ),
                SEQUENCE( 1, table1.columns + table2.columns ) ),
         table2 )
```

In this sense, the formula above is the equivalent of APPEND( table1, table2 ) where APPEND is a row-wise append of two tables which is what we want. *(NB: switch the sequence patterns and you can make a column-wise append.)*

So, hopefully this explanation makes it clear what is happening in the final stages of a variable called **demux** which delivers the result.  I named the result and then referenced it so that you can easily explore, modify or optimize the formula.  So, demux is really like:

```
APPEND( byBody, mux )
```

Then the final output uses this to convert byBody into dates, so it is effectively making something like:

```
APPEND( DATE( demux Col1, Column Index of upMatrix, 1 ), mux )
```

I've tested this, but I've not streamlined it.  The last steps could be combined more efficiently, but I simply haven't had the time to clean that up.  The original code is from a dynamic array unpiv that I built for another similar use.

Answer (score -1):

*This solves the issue:*

**:Caveat:**

*When you use data from F85:H87 for a chart, then Excel will reflect Year, Month along with related data.*

[image]

- Formula in cell F86 & fill across:

  ```
  =IF(ISBLANK(F$85),"",IF(XOR($A86=2000,$A86=2001),INDEX(A$86:A$92,SUMPRODUCT(($A$86:$A$92=2000)*($A$86:$A$92=2001)*ROW($A$86:$A$92)),0),""))
  ```

**N.B.**

- You may replace year 2000 & 2001 with cell references, makes the formula dynamic.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: Please write your concern that why this has been down voted !!